# Selenium Testing in Firefox under session id

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_LoginCorrect (__main__.LoginCorrect)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 12, in test_LoginCorrect
    driver= webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX,command_executor='http://0.0.0.0:4444')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in 

     start_session
     self.session_id = response['sessionId']

TypeError: string indices must be integers

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 20.878s
//Formatting is not properly done

    FAILED (errors=1)
```

My test case file :

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class LoginCorrect(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX) 

def test_LoginCorrect(self):
    user ="shubh"
    pwd= "sha123#56su"
    driver= webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX,command_executor='http://0.0.0.0:4444')
    driver.get("http://0.0.0.0:8000/login")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username")
    elem.send_keys(user)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password")     
    elem.send_keys(pwd)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn-block').click()

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

My machine has Linux 16.04LTS and selenium 3.3.0
Can somebody figure out this problem.

Comment: Why are you creating driver twice once in `setUp` and once in `test_LoginCorrect`?